# Else clause never being reached

Tags: c

I seem to be having a problem writing a string search function. strlength,and strmid are both previously written functions that have been tested and are working.

```
int strfind(char * string1, char * string2)
{
   /* if string1 contains the substring string2 returns
      the starting position of string2 in string1
      otherwise returns -1
      e.g.  strinc("hello world","wor") returns 6
            strinc("hello world","war") returns -1
   */
   int begPos = 0, endPos, count = 0, match = 1;
   char *tempStr;
   endPos = strlength(string2)-1;

   while (endPos <= strlength(string1)-1)
   {
        strmid(string1, begPos, endPos, tempStr);

        while (match == 1)
        {
             if (tempStr[count] == string2[count]) {
                 if (count < strlength(string2)) count++;
                 else break;
              }
              else match = 0;
        }

        if ( match == 1 ) return begPos;
        else { begPos++;
        endPos++; }
   }

   return -1;
}
```

The algorithm should be something like

- Get the segment of the string between begPos and endPos
- Compare this segment with string2
- If they're the same, increment the count and check the next array address
- If not, then the strings do not match and you haven't found the segment in your string 
  yet and match becomes 0.
- If match not found, move the beginning and end position 1 array cell over.
- If match = 1 then return begPos
- Repeat the 6 previous steps until endPos reaches the end of string1.
- If endPos reaches the end of string1 without having found string2 within string1, 
  return -1.

The problem I'm having is that

```
while (match == 1)
{
    if (tempStr[count] == string2[count]) {
         if (count < strlength(string2)) count++;
         else break;
    }
    else match = 0;
}
```

never seems to reach the else clause. The value returned always seems to be the value that begPos is initialized with. This is a homework piece, but I've rewritten it several times using different methods such as for loops, and done multiple dry runs and cannot seem to work out the problem. Any light you can shed would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

espSquall

strmid function

```
void strmid(char * string1, int start, int end, char * string2)
{
   /* copies the elements of string1 from start to end
      to string2  */

   int len, count2 = 0;

   for (len = start; len <= end; len++)
   {
       string2[count2] = string1[len];
       count2++;
   }

   string2[count2] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: tempStr is a char*. Where's it being initialized? I'm assuming it's allocated memory in your strmid() function? If that's the case, you're still not able to use bracket [] notation on it, since it's only a pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have only one point to raise.

How do you think that `tempStr` is getting set to anything useful?

The line `char *tempStr;` sets it to whatever happened to be on the stack at that time while C, with its lack of "proper" pass by reference, cannot change it with the call:

```
strmid(string1, begPos, endPos, tempStr);
```

In order to change the pointer, you would have to pass in `&tempStr` rather than `tempStr`.

So, it appears to me that your `tempStr` is not pointing to anything usable.

---

And, based on your added `strmid` function, this program is definitely in the "undefined behaviour" class. A quick fix, though kludgy, would be to change:

```
char *tempStr;
```

to:

```
char tempStr[1000];
```

That might not fix *all* your problems (and it'll introduce a potential for buffer overflow) but it'll at least give you a well-defined program.

Comment: the strmid function is supposed to copy the segment from string1 between begPos and endPos and copy it into tempStr. The code for strmid is: ... now at the bottom of the original post because I can't work out how to format this part properly.

Comment: I understand that, @espsquall, but you still have the "undefined behaviour" problem that you're copying data to wherever `tempStr` points, and it could point _anywhere!_ And, even if you did allocate the memory for it within strmid (you don't), that would only set the pointer within that function - the `tempStr` within `strfind` will still point to rubbish.

Answer (score 2):

2 points:

- you need to reinitialie `count` to zero before the inner `while`
- you need to reinitialise `match` to 1 before the inner `while`

If you don't do this, then if the first iteration doesn't match, match will never be 1 again, and count will have you checking memory you don't know the content of.

This is in addition to the issue noted by paxdiablo.

Comment: Ahh yea, thanks. THat solves one problem before I get to it :)

Comment: +1, excellent points, those, ones I didn't pick up on. I assume these are both immediately after the call to `strmid` (before the _inner_ while), yes? You might want to make that clear since there are two `while` statements.

Comment: @paxdiablo answer edited :) I don't think it makes much of a difference as long as it is inserted inserted *before* the inner most while.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code:

```
   if (tempStr[count] == string2[count]) {
       if (count < strlength(string2)) count++;
      else break; }
   else match = 0;
```

Can you see how match will never get set to zero?

Comment: What about where `tempStr[count] != string2[count]`?

Comment: sure but if they are equal and count > then len this will go forever.

Comment: that is... the break will not go to the match = 0 statement.  Rewrite this code without break and you will be happy.

Comment: No, the instant count is greater than length, the inner `else break` will fire and you'll exit the loop with match = 1. On the other hand, when you find the characters aren't equal, the `else match = 0` will fire and the outer loop will exit due to its condition. I see no problem there. `break` breaks from a _loop_ (the `while`), not from an `if`.

Answer (score 0):

if ( match == 1 ) return begPos;
else { begPos++;
       endPos++; }

match will always be 1 for it to get here

Comment: No, same deal as with Hogan. If the characters aren't equal in the inner loop, match is set to 0 so that loop exits. In that case, you'll reach that code without match being set to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Just re set match to 1 and count to zero at the start of the loop and allocate sufficient memory for tempStr* :

int endPos = strlen(string2)-1;
char* tempStr = (char*)malloc((size_t)(endPos+1));

while (endPos <= strlength(string1)-1)
   {
      count=0;
      match=1; 
      ...